# Tikz foreach loop and coordinate computation including scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I am trying to plot a number of lines from a point on the segment connecting points from a given list of points to the coordinate origin (0,0). Since I want to automate this procedure, I am using `\foreach`. When I am trying to use the `calc` features to calculate the coordinates of the points I am running into an error.

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\points{(-2,0), (-1.2, 1), (0, 1.55), (0.8, 1.65), (1.3, 1.4), (2, 0.1), (1.8, -0.7), (1,-1.6), (-1, -1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \p in \points{
    \draw[gray!80!white] \p--(0,0);
    \draw[gray, ->] \p--($\p!0.1!(0,0)$);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here the error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \tikz@cc@parse@factor.
```

Note that this question is different from [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341073/tikz-foreach-loop-and-coordinate-computation) since I do not use the `axis` environment.

Comment: Note that you're writing also `...!(0.0)$)`, it should be `...!(0,0)$)`.

Comment: @Alenanno thanks - I completely missed that one.

Comment: A quick and durty hack is to add single `(` at the begining, like this `$(\p!0.1!(0,0)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possible alternatives. In the first one I changed the definition of the `\points` macro to not include `()`, and added those in the code as well. You then need `{}` instead of `()` in `\points` to delimit the entries in the "array".

The other version uses your definition of `\points`, but leaves out the coordinate calculation altogether, using instead a `decoration` to add the arrow tips.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\def\points{{-2,0}, {-1.2, 1}, {0, 1.55}, {0.8, 1.65}, {1.3, 1.4}, {2, 0.1}, {1.8, -0.7}, {1,-1.6}, {-1, -1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \p in \points{
    \draw[gray!80!white] (\p)--(0,0);
    \draw[gray, ->] (\p)--($(\p)!0.1!(0,0)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

% second version
\def\points{(-2,0), (-1.2, 1), (0, 1.55), (0.8, 1.65), (1.3, 1.4), (2, 0.1), (1.8, -0.7), (1,-1.6), (-1, -1)}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.1 with \arrow{>}}]
  \foreach \p in \points
    \draw[gray!80!white, postaction={decorate}] \p--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a simple explanation why the original code did not work? Is it a mistake on my side or is there a bug in one of the packages?

Comment: @Christian I would guess an expansion issue, that the `\p` in  `($\p!0.1!(0,0)$)` isn't expanded so that the parser doesn't "see" that coordinate, but I  don't know. Which I wouldn't necessarily call a bug. I don't know how to fix it either.

Comment: @Christian it has to see a naked `(` to understand that it is a coordinate expression.