# Drawing Grid Lines using \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I am trying to draw gridlines inside a square. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= white,
xmin=-28.9, 
xmax=28.9, 
ymin=-28.9, 
ymax=28.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle,
]

\foreach \x in {-24,..., 24}
    {\draw[thin, gray] (\x,-24) -- (\x,24);}

\draw[black, thin] (-24,-24) -- (-24,24) -- (24,24) -- (24, -24) -- 
(-24,-24);

\node[black, below] at (24,-24) {$(1,0)$};

\node[black, below] at (-24,-24) {$(0,0)$};

\node[black, above] at (-24,24) {$(0,1)$};

\node[black, above] at (24,24) {$(1,1)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This code, however, will not compile. My goal is to make a square with a 24 x 24 grid.

Comment: No grid comes up when I use this. It only produces the square

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works fine if you use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` instead of `\foreach`:

[image]

#### Notes:

- I would suggest you try the `grid` options built into `pgfplots` and `tikz`.
- All the code you showing does not require `pgfplots` so you can eliminate the `axis` environment. So, unless there is other functionality that is not shown in the MWE, you should consider the non-`axis` environment version which uses `\foreach`.

#### References:

- [\foreach not behaving in axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170664/4301)
- [Tikz foreach loop and coordinate computation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341073/4301).

#### Code: `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
%
%\begin{figure}[ht]
%
%\centering
%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=1.25,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
    color= white,
    xmin=-28.9, 
    xmax=28.9, 
    ymin=-28.9, 
    ymax=28.9, 
    axis equal image, 
    axis lines=middle,
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {-24,...,24} {%
    \draw[thin, gray] (#1,-24) -- (#1,24);
}

\draw[black, thin] (-24,-24) -- (-24,24) -- (24,24) -- (24, -24) -- 
(-24,-24);

\node[black, below] at (24,-24) {$(1,0)$};

\node[black, below] at (-24,-24) {$(0,0)$};

\node[black, above] at (-24,24) {$(0,1)$};

\node[black, above] at (24,24) {$(1,1)$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
%\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

#### Code: no `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.10]

\foreach \x in  {-24,...,24} {%
    \draw[thin, gray] (\x,-24) -- (\x,24);
}

\draw[black, thin] (-24,-24) -- (-24,24) -- (24,24) -- (24, -24) -- 
(-24,-24);

\node[black, below] at (24,-24) {$(1,0)$};

\node[black, below] at (-24,-24) {$(0,0)$};

\node[black, above] at (-24,24) {$(0,1)$};

\node[black, above] at (24,24) {$(1,1)$};

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just curious, for using ```\pgfplotsinvokeforeach```, the resulting drawing is what I want, but I get the error message: "Illegal parameter number in definition of \test". It then says "You meant to type ## instead of #, right?" Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @AidenKenny: I am guessng that you are using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` within a macro where `#1` refers to the first parameter of the macro. Thus,  if you are using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` _within_ a macro definition, you need to use `##1` to refer to the parameters of the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.  This is similar to the issue with defening a macro _within_ a macro: where `#1` would refer to the first parameter of the outer macro and `##1` would refe to the first parameter of the inner macro.

Comment: @AidenKenny: If that does not solve your issue, please ask a new question with a  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Two other options without `pgfplots`, one without `foreach` and one with `foreach`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (24,24);
\node[above right] at (24,24) {$(1,1)$};
\node[above left] at (0,24) {$(0,1)$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\node[below right] at (24,0) {$(1,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,24}{
    \draw (\i,0) -- ++(90:24);
    \draw (0,\i) -- ++(0:24);
}
\node[above right] at (24,24) {$(1,1)$};
\node[above left] at (0,24) {$(0,1)$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\node[below right] at (24,0) {$(1,0)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]